# Squeeze Theorem and Trigonometry

Tags: calculus, limits

friends.

Let $f, g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ such that $ |\sin x| \leq f(x) \leq 3|x| $ and $ 0 \leq g(x) \leq 1 + |\sin x| $ for any $ x \in \mathbb{R} $. Calculate $ \lim_{x \to 0} \left ( f(x)g(x) + \cos x\right) $.

Using the Squeeze Theorem, since $ \lim_{x \to 0} |\sin x| = \lim_{x \to 0} 3|x| = 0 $, we get $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0 $.

But, since $ \lim_{x \to 0} 0 \neq \lim_{x \to 0} (1 + |\sin x|) $, I don't know what $ \lim_{x \to 0} g(x) $ is. However, I do know that if said limit exists and is not equal to 0, then $ \lim_{x \to 0} \left( f(x)g(x) + \cos(x) \right) = 1 $.

How can I calculate that limit or at least show that it exists and is not equal to 0?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is irrelevant what $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ is, or even whether it exists. All that matters is that $g$ is bounded near $0$, as evinced by the fact that $0 \le g(x) \le 1 + |\sin(x)| \le 2$. Since $f$ tends to zero, so does $fg$, and the overall limit is thus

$$0 + \lim_{x \to 0} \cos x = 1.$$

---

If you'd like to formalize this with the squeeze theorem, note that

$$|f(x) g(x)| \le 6 |x|$$

which gives the desired result.

Comment: Thank you, mate.
I understood the second idea, but I can't understand why it doesn't matter what $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) $ is and especially whether it exists.

Comment: @PedroCunha The fact that $f$ tends to zero means that whatever bad behaviour $g$ has, it's killed by $f$ (proved that $g$ is bounded...). Compare to a statement such as $$\lim_{x \to 0} x \sin\frac 1 x = 0$$ although $\sin(1/x)$ is a terrible function.

Comment: Hmm.. but if the limit doesn't exist how will the product exist?

Comment: Because $x$ is *very* small and the bad part is bounded.

Comment: I think I understand. Thank you again!

Comment: You're very welcome. I'd suggest you work through the $\epsilon-\delta$ proof of the lemma that states $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) g(x) = 0$ whenever $g$ is bounded and $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ - it's a good experience.